# Snippet that displays the number of friendship requests received

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small php snippet that shows me the number of requests received, this is the code written:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$new_reqs = UM()->Friends_API()->api()->count_friend_requests_received( $user_id );
echo $new_reqs;
```

The snippet works perfectly and shows me the number of requests received. The problem is that if I have not received requests it shows nothing. How can I show 0 if I have not received requests? I've tried adding this code

```
    if (empty($new_reqs)) { echo "0"; }
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: So its not "empty" Try a `var_dump($new_reqs)` to see what is actually in that variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I didn't understand what I have to do. Sorry, but I'm not an expert. Thank you.

Comment: Change this line `echo $new_reqs;` to `var_dump($new_reqs);` Then show us the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following code:

```
echo ($new_reqs > 0) ? $new_reqs : 0 ;
```

That way if requests have been received, it will work as before, else it will print 0.

Comment: Do you know the return value?  That would be an important part of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried, but it doesn't work. If I have not received any friend request, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @C.Allec if that is true then why is this answer accepted?  Your question is Unclear because you haven't told us the return value.